# Unable to install bazel on Ubuntu 14.04 using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, bazel

I tried following commands but keep getting same error everytime:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

But the command `sudo apt-get install bazel` gives same error every time:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bazel
```

How would I be able to install the bazel package?

Comment: Please use proper foramtting.

Comment: Fixed formatting

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` finish without reporting any errors? If not, can you share the log?

Comment: There is long history of porting Bazel into debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782654

Answer (score 4):

Actually there was a **similar problem**:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

I tried the answer voted most, and found that there wasn't a bazel package.

So I went to the **official website of bazel**:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html

I tried the recommended way,"Using Bazel custom APT repository", but got stuck in the 1st step, and I found many similar problems in Google, but nothing helps.

So I tried the 2nd way,"Install using binary installer", thankfully it works!

Here are the **steps** I copied from it(a little changed):

1. Install required packages

   > sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip python
2. Download Bazel

   Go to Bazel's [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases).

   Download the binary installer bazel-0.7.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh(the latest version I got). This installer contains the Bazel binary and the required JDK, and can be used even if JDK is already installed.

   Note that bazel-0.7.0-without-jdk-installer-linux-x86_64.sh also exists. It is a version without embedded JDK 8. Only use this installer if you already have JDK 8 installed.
3. Run the installer

   > chmod +x bazel-0.7.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
   >
   > ./bazel-0.7.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user

   The **--user** flag installs Bazel to the **$HOME/bin** directory on your system and sets the **.bazelrc** path to **$HOME/.bazelrc**. Use the **--help** command to see additional installation options.
4. Set up your environment

   If you ran the Bazel installer with the **--user** flag as above, the Bazel executable is installed in your **$HOME/bin** directory. It's a good idea to add this directory to your default paths, as follows:

   > export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"

   You can also add this command to your **~/.bashrc** file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

1. `echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. `sudo apt update`

**This Works**

Comment: beware of doing `echo "<list>" > /etc/apt/sources.list` it can potentially wipe off anything in `sources.list`. Instead use `>>` to append to the `sources.list`.

Comment: DO NOT EVER TELL PEOPLE TO APT UPDATE. IT CAN BREAK THEIR ENTIRE DEVELOPMENT TOOLCHAIN, ESPECIALLY FOR THINGS LIKE DEEPSPEECH.

Comment: this is a very dangerous command! , someone should edit it and replace `>` with `>>`

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a one-time setup step.

`sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg

curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor > bazel.gpg

sudo mv bazel.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list`

The component name “jdk1.8” is kept only for legacy reasons and doesn’t relate to supported or included JDK versions. Bazel releases are Java-version agnostic. Changing the “jdk1.8” component name would break existing users of the repo.

Step 2: Install and update Bazel

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel`

Once installed, you can upgrade to a newer version of Bazel as part of your normal system updates