# Updating bazel on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: tensorflow

I followed this step by step guide here:
https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md

in order to install and build Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
But, when I reach the point it says:

```
./configure
```

I get this error:

> You have bazel 0.4.5- (@non-git) installed. Please upgrade your bazel
>   installation to version 0.19.0 or higher to build TensorFlow!

**Then I followed these instructions:**

[Unable to install bazel on Ubuntu 14.04 using apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767275/unable-to-install-bazel-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-apt-get)

and used the file:

```
bazel-0.22.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

**from here:**

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases

but when I am trying ./configure, I got again the same message. I spent two days searching google and tutorials, doing nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the "*bazel-0.22.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh*" as your CPU is ARM architecture not x86_64.

Try to follow this guide: https://gist.github.com/EKami/9869ae6347f68c592c5b5cd181a3b205#3-build-bazel